# Filtrar un datagrid a través de la selección de una fecha en un calendario

Tags: .net, datagrid, vb, calendario

```
dg_datos.Columns.Add("tarea", "Tarea")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("horas", "Horas")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("descripcion", "Descripcion")
    dg_datos.Columns.Add("fecha", "Fecha")


    dg_datos.Rows.Add("Ada Lovelace", 1, "desc.1", #11/10/2002#)
```

Esta es la creacion de las tablas y aqui abajo esta como intento filtrar a traves de la seleccion de una fecha en el calendario

```
    Private Sub Calendario_DateSelected(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles calendario.DateSelected
    Dim table As New DataTable
    BindingSource1.DataSource = table
    dg_datos.DataSource = BindingSource1

    BindingSource1.Filter = String.Format("fecha = #{0:M/dd/yyyy}#", calendario.SelectionStart)

End Sub
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Tengo un datagrid con datos, y una columna es "fecha" y quiero que cuando yo pulse una fecha de un calendario que tengo creado, me enseñe los datos que hay en ese dia(en esa fecha)